# Download packages of assets in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I've written a phonegap App which gets its data from a JSON file which provides text to display and paths Amazon S3 hosted images, because the App is used in areas without signal a lot of the time it has to be able to download and Cache all content.

Is there a more elegant way to download packages of images than requesting every image individually and then saving it? Ideally I'd like to download a single package (e.g. a zip file) and then extract it to the phones file system after download as doing it image by image means a lot of individual HTTP requests which introduces substantial delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you would use the FileTransfer class to download the .zip to your sdcard then you'd have to write a plugin to do the unzip. Luckily Android includes the java.util.zip package so you wouldn't have to import any additional libraries in order to do an unzip.

Comment: I actually ended up encoding all of the images with base64 and including them in the JSON output then caching the JASON in localstorage but your answer looks spot on for the approach I'd asked the question about.